# WORD VBA Sort Ascending and Sort Descending

Tags: sorting, vba, ms-word

Here is code I have that sorts the words inside an array into ascending order. I need help to change it in such a way that it will also sort the words in descending order, all in a single function. Please help. Thanks!

```
Function Sort_Asc(ByRef str() As String)
     Dim iLower As Integer, iUpper As Integer, iCount As Integer, Temp As String
     Dim str2 As String
           iUpper = UBound(str)
           iLower = 1
           Dim bSorted As Boolean
           bSorted = False
           Do While Not bSorted
                bSorted = True
                For iCount = iLower To iUpper - 1
                str2 = StrComp(str(iCount), str(iCount + 1), vbTextCompare)
                     If str2 = 1 Then
                           Temp = str(iCount + 1)
                           str(iCount + 1) = str(iCount)
                           str(iCount) = Temp
                           bSorted = False
                     End If
                Next iCount
             iUpper = iUpper - 1
           Loop
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about

```
Function Sort(ByRef str() As String, ByVal booAsc As Boolean)
 Dim iLower As Integer, iUpper As Integer, iCount As Integer, Temp As String
 Dim str2 As String

       iUpper = UBound(str)
       iLower = 1

       Dim bSorted As Boolean
       bSorted = False
       Do While Not bSorted
            bSorted = True
            For iCount = iLower To iUpper - 1
            If booAsc Then
                str2 = StrComp(str(iCount + 1), str(iCount), vbTextCompare)
            Else
                str2 = StrComp(str(iCount), str(iCount + 1), vbTextCompare)
            End If
                 If str2 = 1 Then
                       Temp = str(iCount + 1)
                       str(iCount + 1) = str(iCount)
                       str(iCount) = Temp
                       bSorted = False
                 End If
            Next iCount
         iUpper = iUpper - 1
       Loop
End Function
```

and call the function using `Sort strArray, False '(False Ascending, True Descending)`

Comment: thanks got this one working. appreciate the help there buddy!